# problem to change a contact with google contacts api

Tags: php, google-contacts-api, php-curl

I'm trying to change a Google contact via PHP, but for every request the Google server doesn't answer me. If I try to post the google server in NULL I get invalid XML, so I think the PUT request is correct.
Can anyone help me with some examples?
This is the code in PHP

```
$access = 'xxx';
$user_email = urlencode('xxx@xxx');
$id_contatto = 'xxx';

$contactXML = '
    <entry gd:etag="*">
    <id>http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/'.$user_email.'/base/'.$id_contatto.'</id>
    <updated>2019-05-27T17:07:02.303Z</updated>
    <atom:category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind" term="http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact"/>
    <gd:name>
        <gd:givenName>Test</gd:givenName>
        <gd:familyName>Test</gd:familyName>
        <gd:fullName>Test Test</gd:fullName>
    </gd:name>
    <content type="text">Notes</content>
    <link rel="http://schemas.google.com/contacts/2008/rel#photo" type="image/*" href="https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/'.$user_email.'/'.$id_contatto.'"/>
    <link rel="self" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/'.$user_email.'/full/'.$id_contatto.'"/>
    <link rel="edit" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/'.$user_email.'/full/'.$id_contatto.'"/>
    <gd:phoneNumber rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#other" primary="true">456-123-2133</gd:phoneNumber>
    <gd:extendedProperty name="pet" value="hamster"/>
    <gd:groupMembershipInfo deleted="false" href="http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/'.$user_email.'/base/6"/>
    </entry>
    </pre>';

$headers = array(
'If-Match: *',
'Gdata-version: 3.0',
'Content-type: application/atom+xml',
);

$contactQuery = 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/'.$id_contatto.'?access_token='.$access;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $contactQuery );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $contactXML);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if(curl_errno($ch)){
    $result = curl_error($ch);
}

var_dump($result);
```

This is the result of the var_dump after the timeout:

string(0) ""

Comment: Maybe use their API instead? https://developers.google.com/people/v1/getting-started

Comment: No the APIs I have to use are these
https://developers.google.com/contacts/v3/#updating_contacts